# Can't start NameNode daemon and DataNode daemon in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, ssh, mapreduce, ssh-keys

I am trying to run Hadoop in Pseudo-Distributed mode. For this I am trying to follow this tutorial http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

I can ssh to my localhost and Format the filesystem. However, I can't start NameNode daemon and DataNode daemon by this command :

```
    sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

When I execute it with sudo I get:

```
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-67:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0$ sudo sbin/start-dfs.sh 
    Starting namenodes on [localhost]
    localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
    localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
    Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0] 
    0.0.0.0: Permission denied (publickey).
```

and when executed without sudo:

```
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-67:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0$ sbin/start-dfs.sh 
    Starting namenodes on [localhost]
    localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs’: Permission denied
    localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs’: No such file or directory
    localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode-ip-172-31-42-67.out
    localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode-ip-172-31-42-67.out: No such file or directory
    localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode-ip-172-31-42-67.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
    localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode-ip-172-31-42-67.out: No such file or directory
    localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode-ip-172-31-42-67.out: No such file or directory
    localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs’: Permission denied
    localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs’: No such file or directory
    localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-ip-172-31-42-67.out
    localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-ip-172-31-42-67.out: No such file or directory
    localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-ip-172-31-42-67.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
    localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-ip-172-31-42-67.out: No such file or directory
    localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-ip-172-31-42-67.out: No such file or directory
    Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
    0.0.0.0: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs’: Permission denied
    0.0.0.0: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs’: No such file or directory
    0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-secondarynamenode-ip-172-31-42-67.out
    0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-secondarynamenode-ip-172-31-42-67.out: No such file or directory
    0.0.0.0: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-secondarynamenode-ip-172-31-42-67.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
    0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-secondarynamenode-ip-172-31-42-67.out: No such file or directory
    0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-secondarynamenode-ip-172-31-42-67.out: No such file or directory
```

I also notice now that when executing ls to check content of hfs directories like here, it fails:

```
   ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-67:~/dir$ hdfs dfs -ls output/
   ls: Call From ip-172-31-42-67.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.42.67 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors above suggest a permissions problem.
You have to make sure that the hadoop user has the proper privileges to /usr/local/hadoop.
For this purpose you can try:

```
   sudo chown -R hadoop /usr/local/hadoop/
```

Or

```
   sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/hadoop/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the only solution I found was:

https://anuragsoni.wordpress.com/2015/07/05/hadoop-start-dfs-sh-localhost-permission-denied-how-to-fix/

Which suggest you to **generate a new ssh-rsa key**

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you do the following "Configuration" correctly, you need to edit 4 ".xml" files:

Edit the file hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml , between  , put in :

```
 <property>        
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>        
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>   
 </property>
```

Edit the file hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml, between  put in:

```
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
```

Edit the file hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xm, between  paste the following and save

```
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
```

Edit the file  hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml, between  paste the following and save

```
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
```