# Hadoop start-dfs.sh permission denied for “ubuntu” user

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs

I am trying to setup a 4 node cluster on Amazon aws.
All the installation, setup and configuration has been done, but facing and issue while executing "start-dfs.sh" command.

following is the error message:

```
Starting namenodes on [ec2-13-126-215-231.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com]
ec2-13-126-215-231.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).

datanode2: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-ip-172-31-30-218.out

datanode3: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-ip-172-31-18-165.out

datanode1: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-ip-172-31-19-66.out

Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have tried followings as well

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu /usr/local/hadoop
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/hadoop
```

but still facing the same error.

Please help me to resolve this error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had the same problem, and found [this](https://anuragsoni.wordpress.com/2015/07/05/hadoop-start-dfs-sh-localhost-permission-denied-how-to-fix/) helpful in [Can't start NameNode daemon and DataNode daemon in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059250/cant-start-namenode-daemon-and-datanode-daemon-in-hadoop).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the chmod command into the file, not the folder. For example:

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/hadoop/start-dfs.sh
```

OR:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/local/hadoop/
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your response. I Tried both of these, bur same error.